# Qt Stylesheet targeting a specific groupbox by title

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qt-creator, qtstylesheets

I want to have different stylesheet for groupboxes with title and those without title like this

groupboxes with title: `margin-top:5px`

groupboxes with empty title: `margin-top:0px`

I think this should be done by changing stylesheet for all groupboxes then target groupboxes that have empty title

I’ve tried this but no success

```
    this->setStyleSheet("QGroupBox{border: 1px solid black; border-radius:3px; margin-top:5px;}"
                        "QGroupBox::title{top:-5px}"
                        "QGroupBox[title=""]{border: 1px solid black; margin-top:0px}"
                        );
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: Please provide a valid [mre] (with proper characters, as `“”` are not valid string delimiters). Also be aware about the warning in the [Selector Types](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-syntax.html#selector-types) section of the documentation regarding the "property selector": «If the value of the Qt property changes after the style sheet has been set, it might be necessary to force a style sheet recomputation». Title changes of a groupbox done at runtime will have absolutely **no** effect based on the style sheet.

Comment: @musicamante thank for comment i've edited the question. there is no specific info about Property Selector of groupbox title in the link you provided. Also the title stays the same

Comment: That page is about generic usage, and I was pointing it in case the issue was about a changing property. In any case, try with `QGroupBox[title] { ... }`.

Comment: I tried that but no success

Comment: What did you try? I just tested the following, and does exactly what you want: `QGroupBox{ border: 1px solid black; margin-top: 0; } QGroupBox[title] { margin-top: 5px; }`. See the result: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RCkdr.png (I added a green border for the container to highlight the margin differences).

Comment: how did you set the stylesheet? From mainwindow.ui or using `setStyleSheet()`? You've probably used the stylesheet option in mainwidow.ui designer, that works without any problem. My problem as I mentioned is using `this->setStyleSheet();`

Comment: I can do that in any combination: from Designer, by calling `setStyleSheet()` for the QApplication, for any parent widget, and even for the individual groupboxes. In fact, there should be absolutely no difference, unless you are *also* setting a stylesheet somewhere else. Besides, if it *did* work for you in Designer, you should've specified it. In any case, since you see a different behavior, please provide a proper [mre], as right now we don't even know what `this` is.